# How to distribute width in according to module count?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, position, joomla-template, joomla3.3

I am trying to make a joomla template. I am also using bootstrap v2.3.2. I want to make a design 3/12-6/12-3/12 distribution. 
I am checking if any modules are positioned on the left and right columns

```
$span = 12;

if ($this->countModules('right')) $span -= 3;
if ($this->countModules('left'))  $span -= 3;

<?php if ($this->countModules('left')): ?>
    <div id="sidebarleft" class="span3">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="well" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="content" class="span<?php echo $span; ?>">
    <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>

<?php if ($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
    <div id="sidebarright" class="span3">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="none" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have assigned a `mod_articles_category` module to left position but it is empty. So the module is not shown. But joomla thinks that there is a module in that position and it has to shrink content with.

How can I use the space if module is not shown on a page?

Answer (score 0):

You should change

"`<?php echo $span; ?>`" into **"`span<?php echo $span; ?>`"**

In that way, the result is:

**`<div id="content" class="span12">`** instead of `<div id="content" class="12">`

Comment: thanks. but it is already `span<?php echo $span; ?>`. I forgot to write it.